# Prototypical inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript's prototypical inheritance and js object-oriented programming. I was trying to create a base object, Account and then inherit the CheckingAccount from it. The following is my code.

```
function Account(fName, lName) {
   this.firstName = fName;
   this.lastName = lName;

 }

 Account.prototype.balance = function() {
    console.log("This is the balance");
 }

 function CheckingAccount() {

    this.salary = 10000;
 }

 CheckingAccount.prototype = Object.create(Account.prototype);

 let account = new Account("John", "Doe");
 let checking = new CheckingAccount();
 CheckingAccount.balance();
```

When I run it on Visual Studio, I am getting the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: CheckingAccount.balance is not a function"

Comment: you have to use the instance: `checking.balance()`

Comment: Also, your `CheckingAccount` should call the super constructor, and pass first and last name. The `new Account("John", "Doe")` is a separate object, you wouldn't be able to access the names on the `checking` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call the method on the instance and not the Class object (e.g., `checking` not `CheckingAccount`).  Also, make sure to change the constructor. For further reading, refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance).

You can see these changes here:

```js
function Account(fName, lName) {
  this.firstName = fName;
  this.lastName = lName;
  this.salary = 0;
}

Account.prototype.balance = function() {
  return this.salary;    // you'll probably not use _only_ salary here
}

function CheckingAccount() {
  this.salary = 10000;
}

CheckingAccount.prototype = Object.create(Account.prototype);
// Make sure to update the constructor
Object.defineProperty(CheckingAccount.prototype, 'constructor', {
  value: CheckingAccount,
  enumerable: false, // so that it does not appear in 'for in' loop
  writable: true
});

let account  = new Account("John", "Doe");
let checking = new CheckingAccount();

console.log('account balance:',      account.balance())
console.log('checking balance:',     checking.balance())
console.log('account constructor:',  account.constructor);
console.log('checking constructor:', checking.constructor);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. For each inherited property should I include code similar to this: Account.prototype.balance = function () {
    return this.salary;    
}

Comment: @Massey all this does is extend the prototype functions to another "class".  You are explicitly enforcing inheritance through this assignment.  In the case of `balance()` it is a method on the superclass, so if you want that to be available in each subclass, you should define it.  You don't need to define it, though.  There are no strict rules.  You can also overwrite it -- in your example, with `CheckingAccount.prototype.balance = function() { /* something else */ };`. It all depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the proper `class` keyword in ES6.  Here's an example of Account and Chequing which extends it.  Here the `Account` class has a `balance`, `deposit` and `showBook` function, and only the child `Chequing` class has a `writeCheque` function. Yet the `Chequing` instance can still call all parent class functions since it's an `Account`.

```js
class Account {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = 0;
  }
  balance() {
    return this.amount
  }
  deposit(sum) {
    this.amount += sum;
  }
  showBook() {
    console.log("-------------------------");
    console.log("Account for",this.name);
    console.log(`Balance: $${this.amount}`);
  }
}

class Chequing extends Account {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
    this.cheques = [];
  }
  writeCheque(sum, to) {
    this.amount -= sum;
    this.cheques.push({number: this.cheques.length+1, recipient: to, amount: sum});
  }
  showBook() {
    super.showBook();
    if (this.cheques.length > 0) {
      console.log("Cheque activity:");
      for (const cheque of this.cheques) {
        console.log(`  ${cheque.number}: $${cheque.amount} paid to ${cheque.recipient}`);
      }
    }
    else console.log("No cheques have been written");
  }
}

const ch1 = new Chequing("Mary Jones");
ch1.deposit(1000);
ch1.showBook();
ch1.writeCheque(95, "Bob Smith");
ch1.writeCheque(485, "Ritz Hotel");
ch1.showBook();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Account** is class here.
**CheckingAccount** is class too.
the **account** and **checking** are instances.

if you want the **CheckingAccount** to inherit from **Account** class, you should, and did this:

```
CheckingAccount.prototype = Object.create(Account.prototype);
```

*This delegates CheckingAccount's prototype object to Accounts prototype object.*

There is no **balance** property in **CheckingAccount** function (*functions are first-class objects in javascript*),  there is only **prototype** property on it. Though the **balance** property, which is the function same time, resides on the object, where Account's prototype property points to *(balance function is inside of Account.prototype object in short)*.

The function `balance()` is accessible from:

- Account.prototype
- CheckingAccount.prototype *(because of the Object.create function you
  used)*
- From any instances of both these classes.